AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map
When I installed fairseq using
pip install --editable ./

The following error came out. I updated the pip version, but it was in vain.
(pytorch) G:\self-supervised\unilm-master\YOCO\yoco\models\fairseq>pip install --editable ./
Obtaining file:///G:/self-supervised/unilm-master/YOCO/yoco/models/fairseq
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build editable ... done
  Preparing editable metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: cffi in d:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from fairseq==0.12.2) (1.17.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cython in d:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from fairseq==0.12.2) (3.0.11)
Requirement already satisfied: hydra-core<1.1,>=1.0.7 in d:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from fairseq==0.12.2) (1.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: omegaconf<2.1 in d:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from fairseq==0.12.2) (2.0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.3 in d:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from fairseq==0.12.2) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: regex in d:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from fairseq==0.12.2) (2024.7.24)
Requirement already satisfied: sacrebleu>=1.4.12 in d:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from fairseq==0.12.2) (2.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: torch>=1.13 in d:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from fairseq==0.12.2) (2.0.1+cu118)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in d:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from fairseq==0.12.2) (4.66.5)
Requirement already satisfied: bitarray in d:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from fairseq==0.12.2) (2.9.2)
Requirement already satisfied: torchaudio>=0.8.0 in d:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from fairseq==0.12.2) (2.0.2+cu118)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in d:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from fairseq==0.12.2) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in d:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from fairseq==0.12.2) (24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: antlr4-python3-runtime==4.8 in d:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from hydra-core<1.1,>=1.0.7->fairseq==0.12.2) (4.8)
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3367, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3147, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 36, in __init__
    parsed = _parse_requirement(requirement_string)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\_parser.py", line 62, in parse_requirement
    return _parse_requirement(Tokenizer(source, rules=DEFAULT_RULES))
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\_parser.py", line 80, in _parse_requirement
    url, specifier, marker = _parse_requirement_details(tokenizer)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\_parser.py", line 118, in _parse_requirement_details
    specifier = _parse_specifier(tokenizer)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\_parser.py", line 214, in _parse_specifier
    parsed_specifiers = _parse_version_many(tokenizer)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\_parser.py", line 229, in _parse_version_many
    tokenizer.raise_syntax_error(
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\_tokenizer.py", line 167, in raise_syntax_error
    raise ParserSyntaxError(
pip._vendor.packaging._tokenizer.ParserSyntaxError: .* suffix can only be used with `==` or `!=` operators
    PyYAML (>=5.1.*)
            ~~~~~~^

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 105, in _run_wrapper
    status = _inner_run()
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 96, in _inner_run
    return self.run(options, args)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 67, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 379, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 95, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 546, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 427, in resolve
    failure_causes = self._attempt_to_pin_criterion(name)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 239, in _attempt_to_pin_criterion
    criteria = self._get_updated_criteria(candidate)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 229, in _get_updated_criteria
    for requirement in self._p.get_dependencies(candidate=candidate):
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\provider.py", line 247, in get_dependencies
    return [r for r in candidate.iter_dependencies(with_requires) if r is not None]
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\provider.py", line 247, in <listcomp>
    return [r for r in candidate.iter_dependencies(with_requires) if r is not None]
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 401, in iter_dependencies
    for r in self.dist.iter_dependencies():
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\metadata\pkg_resources.py", line 247, in iter_dependencies
    return self._dist.requires(extras)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3070, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3369, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3379, in _compute_dependencies
    reqs.extend(parse_requirements(req))
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3434, in __init__
    super().__init__(requirement_string)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 38, in __init__
    raise InvalidRequirement(str(e)) from e
pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: .* suffix can only be used with `==` or `!=` operators
    PyYAML (>=5.1.*)


This is your real error: pip._vendor.packaging._tokenizer.ParserSyntaxError: .* suffix can only be used with \==` or `!=` operators PyYAML (>=5.1.*)`. See https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairseq/issues?q=is%3Aissue+InvalidRequirement
